# Script or batch file for editing desktop.ini file

Tags: batch-file, desktop.ini

I am using 64bit Windows 10 Pro v1607 build 14393.693
How do I modify every desktop.ini file on my system?
I have a small SSD C drive and a large HD E drive.
I moved my Icon folder off of the C drive and put the Icon folder on the E drive.
Now all my custom set icons do not show.
How do I modify every desktop.ini file on my system?
Inside one desktop.ini file for example is:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\Icons\microsoft 1.ico,0
```

I would like to remove C:\Windows\System32 and substitute E:\
The resulting desktop.ini file string for this one example would be:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
IconResource=E:\Icons\microsoft 1.ico,0
```

I would like to apply this substitution to every desktop.ini file containing
the string C:\Windows\System32
Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  It appears that this code would change all to the one specific icon. What I need to do is to only alter part of the string.  If one folder contains IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\media.ico,0 then that changes to IconResource=E:\Icons\media.ico,0  If IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\music_note.ico,0 then IconResource=E:\Icons\music_note.ico,0   If IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\gsp omega composer.ico,0 then IconResource=E:\Icons\gsp omega composer.ico,0  I hope this clarifies my intended request.  Thanks for any new insight.

Comment: Thanks for the coding information.  I will consider this case closed.  Thanks again. Ed44

Answer (score 1):

As, per my knowledge - Every Folder in your Computer (windows) contains a **Desktop.ini** File, which defines the icons for the folder too (and much more). We can easily ***Crawl*** through All the folders and modify its **Desktop.ini** file.

```
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set _Counter=0
Set _Files=0
Cls

REM Crawling through folders and injecting our own lines...
For %%A in (A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z) Do (
    If Exist "%%A:" If "%%A:" NEQ "!SystemDrive!" (
        Cd /D "%%A:"
        Cd /
        For /f "Tokens=*" %%B in ('dir /s /b *.* /a:d') Do (
            If Exist "%%B\Desktop.ini" (
                Set _Counter=0
                For /f "Usebackq Tokens=1,2 delims==" %%C in ("%%B\Desktop.ini") Do (
                    Set /A _Counter+=1
                    IF /I "%%C" == "IconResource" (
                        Set "_Icon_Path=%%D"
                        If /I "!_Icon_Path:~0,19!" == "C:\Windows\System32" (Set "_Line[!_Counter!]=%%C=!_Icon_Path:C:\Windows\System32=E:!")
                        ) ELSE (IF /I "%%D" == "" (Set "_Line[!_Counter!]=%%C") ELSE (Set "_Line[!_Counter!]=%%C=%%D")
                    )
                )
                Call :Saveit !_Counter! "%%~B"
                Set /a _Files+=1
         )
    )
)
)

Echo. You are Done in all the Drives. :^)
Echo. Total Files modified= %_Files%
Echo. 

Pause


REM Extra Function...
:Saveit
Del /Q "%~2\Desktop.ini" >nul
For /L %%A in (1,1,%~1) Do (echo.!_Line[%%A]!>>"%~2\Desktop.ini")
Goto :Eof
```

Again updated as per your last line of question and suggestions in the comments, Now you can know that... it replaces 'C:\windows\system32' from the result. only if the file exists and only if the iconresource contains the above string in the 2nd token. :)

This will definitely solve your problems in all the existing drives. And, to modify in Sensitive areas - I recommend to run it as admin.

## TheBATeam

Comment: Please, Note: Program will take a bit of time - to Scan through Your **SystemDrive** (i.e. C Drive - if windows is installed in C).

The More the folders in a Drive, The More time it'll take to scan - But, It'll definitely do Your Job. :)

Comment: If That's the case - You can Modify the 5th line as Follows: (Don't run as admin Now)

**`If Exist "%%A:"`** to** `If Exist "%%A:" If "%%A:" NEQ "!SystemDrive!"`**

And, For this to work... Add this simple Line after the **Echo Off**:
**`SetLocal Enabledelayedexpansion`**

[http://www.thebateam.org/2017/01/wtf-difference-between-variable-var-var.html] (Reason to add this extra line)

Comment: `desktop.ini` files have many different `LocalizedResourceName` strings and `IconResource` strings and are generally `UTF-16 LE, BOM` I would strongly advise against using the above code to blindly change every single one on your drives to the same string.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input.  It appears that this code would change all to the one specific icon. What I need to do is to only alter part of the string.  If one folder contains IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\media.ico,0 then that changes to IconResource=E:\Icons\media.ico,0  If IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\music_note.ico,0 then IconResource=E:\Icons\music_note.ico,0    If IconResource=C:\Windows\System32\icons\gsp omega composer.ico,0 then IconResource=E:\Icons\gsp omega composer.ico,0  I hope this clarifies my intended request.  Thanks for any new insight.

Comment: :) Again, updated the code for better reults. I hope this fulfils the requirement (pointed out in your last para of question) - read 2nd last para of my answer too. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Desktop.ini editör is a portable freeware to simplify the Desktop.ini operations , it can help you to edit desktop.ini files and set custom folder icons , Folder Info Tips , adding CLSID , reset folder settings to default usw.

Home page 
http://www.sordum.org/10084/desktop-ini-editor-v1-0/